# How to remove the BG image on jQueryUI autocomplete combo (select)

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to style the jQueryUI autocomplete, and can't for the life of me find out how to override the styles on the dropdown list on hover!

(I'm after a clean flat look, no image or gradient).

I've created a plunkr which illustrates the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/pUdcIRgWDcnfuKYVpyQV?p=preview

I've had success with all the other jQUI elements, but not this one.  I've gone through the CSS files, too, but I wonder if something is being added by JS whilst I can't observe it in Chrome?

Even inspecting it in Chrome is fiddly (I suggest right-clicking on the exposed `<li>`)

Any suggestions welcome, Thanks

### jQueryUI styles in jquery.ui.theme.min69d2.css

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    /* this is the damned hover!! */
    border:1px solid #999;
    background:#dadada url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#212121;

    /* an override in place: this works */
    border: none;
    background-image: none;
    background: yellow;
    color:blue;
}
```

### my stylesheet, which comes after jqueryUI and is more specific ( under an #id )

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    /* fails */
    border: none !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    background: yellow !important;
    color:blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's workign as a list, the class for those items is `.ui-menu-item`

Review this code **http://plnkr.co/edit/DQFOCVKIIBysKc4JQGtW?p=preview**

```
.ui-autocomplete, .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item, .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a {
  background:none;
}
.ui-autocomplete {
  background:orange;
}
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item {
  background:red;
}
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a:hover {
  background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thats headed in the right direction! I notice, that when I move my cursor to the very edge of the li, the old style still shows, and I haven't been able to remove it altogether (and this edit doesn't seem to work on my actual code !)

Comment: Try to do more especific the .ui-menu-item check this http://plnkr.co/edit/DQFOCVKIIBysKc4JQGtW?p=preview

Comment: ach, your code works a treat in the plunkr.. very sweet.. I had gotten too specific, and made #selected myself out of the equation.. case closed!  tx so much for your time!

Comment: (for the sake of those who come after, would you paste those lines into your answer? many tx!)

Comment: This doesn't seem to style the state where the item is selected.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 you can try adding the `:active` state

Answer (score 1):

For others that may run into this from the sass side of things, if you happen to be using `jquery-ui-sass-rails` gem (or another sass variation), you can simply add this before your import of `jquery.ui.all`

```
$bgImgUrlHover: none;
```

You might also be interested in `$bgColorHover`.

The relevant sass is:

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    border: 1px solid $borderColorHover;
    background: $bgColorHover $bgImgUrlHover $bgHoverXPos $bgHoverYPos $bgHoverRepeat;
    font-weight: $fwDefault;
    color: $fcHover;
}
```

[Here is a full list of jquery.ui sass variables](https://github.com/jhilden/jquery-ui-sass-rails/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/themes/_jquery.ui.base.css.scss)